# USSD service messages in android

Tags: android, ussd

Is there any method to block ussd messages from a particular center in android application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android **doesn't support USSD service** so we cant bloc it , or cant fetch any Data from USSD or we cant Block it.

Comment: you can do vote up if u like my answer

Comment: False - Android supports USSD just fine.